# convert list to tuples to avoid maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000 in python sql query

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have list in python, I have converted this list to oracle sql list to make a sql query, but there is error  **maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000** and I want to convert this list to tuples so that I can work around this error.
this list varies from time to time with random numbers.

MY Code

```
# convert column to list

samples_numbers = samples.loc[:, "cut_num"].values.tolist()

# convert python list  to sql list

sqllist = str(samples_numbers)
sqllist = sqllist.replace("[", "(").replace("]", ")")

# statment to make query read from list

statment = "select from sample_table where data in" + sqllist 
result  = pd.read_sql_query(statement, engine)
```

What I want my code instead of **select from sample table where data in (500,507,5007,5008,....,100000)**
to be **select from sample table where data in ((500,0),(507,0),(5007,0),(5008,0),....,(100000,0))** to avoid **maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000**

the error message
sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) ORA-01795: maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000

Comment: I don't think this will work; I should think you need to split up the list into chunks and run multiple queries.

Comment: so if you have proper solution, so please submit here

Answer (score 1):

Once you generate your `list` using this

```
samples_numbers = samples.loc[:, "cut_num"].values.tolist()
```

You can create variable `sqlite` of empty list and then `append` each value of that list based on the condition `(504,0),(507,0)....(100000,0)`

```
sqllist = []

for each in samples_numbers:
    sqllist.append((each, 0))
```

Then you can convert that `sqlite` type to `tuple` using this:

```
sqllist = tuple(sqllist)
```

---

## Output

```
print(sqlite)
((500, 0), (507, 0), ..., (100000, 0))
```